# How can I get started parsing binary files in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parsing, binaryfiles

I have some binary files I'd like to be able to parse within the browser. I have found [some python code that (I think) does exactly what I need](https://github.com/mhamann/songshow-converter/blob/master/songshowplus.py) but I don't understand python enough to interpret what I'm seeing.

I have some [sample files on my own code repository](https://github.com/FiniteLooper/SongShowPlus-parser/tree/main/sample-files), and below is my attempt at parsing these files. You can drag files into the snippet window to parse that file

```js
const elBody = document.body;
const dragClass = "drag-over";

const fReader = new FileReader();
fReader.onload = function (e) {
    const data = e.target.result;
    processFile(data);
};

elBody.addEventListener("dragover", (dragEvent) => {
  dragEvent.preventDefault();
  if (!elBody.classList.contains(dragClass)) {
    elBody.classList.add(dragClass);
  }
});
elBody.addEventListener("dragleave", () => {
  elBody.classList.remove(dragClass);
});
elBody.addEventListener("drop", (dropEvent) => {
  dropEvent.preventDefault();
  elBody.classList.remove(dragClass);
  [...dropEvent.dataTransfer.items].forEach((item, i) => {
    if (item.kind === "file") {
      const file = item.getAsFile();
      fReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file, 'utf-8');
    }
  });
});

function processFile(arrayBuffer){
    const byteLength = 4;

    const b1 = new Int32Array(arrayBuffer.slice(0, byteLength))[0]
    console.log(b1)

    // for (let startIdx = 0; startIdx < arrayBuffer.byteLength; startIdx += byteLength) {
    //     const byte = new Int32Array(arrayBuffer.slice(startIdx, startIdx + byteLength))[0]
    //     console.log(byte)
    // }
}
```

```css
 html,body {height: 100vh;margin: 0;}
.drag-over {background-color: #ccc;}
```

```html
<h1>Drop a file here</h1>
```

I am just not sure if I am on the correct track or not. My only source for information about how these type of files are structured come from [these comments in the python file](https://github.com/mhamann/songshow-converter/blob/master/songshowplus.py#L55-L72)

How do I take that information about the file format and convert that into a way to perform the same actions in JavaScript?

Comment: What is the expected output? There is not much you can do with the parsed file. Do you want to convert to base64 and/or make blobs?

Comment: I want to extract the data. It's a song presentation file format, so mainly I want to get the song lyrics out of it. There is some other metadata as well I'd like to get such as the song section titles like "verse 1" or "chorus", etc.

Comment: Why not make a typed array around the whole buffer instead of making a one item array over and over again?

Comment: I've never worked with binary data before, so I have no context for what might work better here or what is possible.  I'll take any tips you can provide to point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me on your [first example file](https://github.com/FiniteLooper/SongShowPlus-parser/raw/main/sample-files/Be%20Near.sbsong).

Less so on the Spanish one with wingdings in it

If you need to parse the text it can be implemented fairly easily.

The [dataview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) is useful here

```js
const processFile = (arrayBuffer) => {
  let offset = 0;
  const dataView = new DataView(arrayBuffer);
  // Read the first 4 bytes as a 32-bit integer; true denotes little-endian
  const firstInteger = dataView.getInt32(offset, true); 
  console.log("First integer:", firstInteger);
  // Increment the offset by 4 bytes
  offset += 4;
  // Loop through the buffer and read bytes based on the context
  let outputString = "";
  while (offset < arrayBuffer.byteLength) {
    // Read one byte to identify the character set
    const char = dataView.getInt8(offset);
    offset += 1;
    // If the char code is a printable ASCII character, append to output string
    if (char >= 32 && char <= 126) {
      
      outputString += String.fromCharCode(char);
    }
    // If the char code corresponds to a newline, add a newline character
    else if (char === 10) {
      outputString += "\n";
    }
    // For other cases, handle them based on your specific needs
    // for example your paragraph markers
  }
  outputString = outputString
    .replace(/%(\w+)/g,"<h2>$1</h2>")
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = outputString;
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.drag-over {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
pre { margin-bottom: 120px; }
```

```html
<h1>Drop a file here</h1>
<pre id="output"></pre>
<hr/>
<script>
  // file reader code - no modified except to add identifiers

  const fReader = new FileReader();
  fReader.onload = function(e) {
    const data = e.target.result;
    processFile(data);
  };
  const dragClass = "drag-over"
  elBody = document.querySelector("h1");
  elBody.addEventListener("dragover", (dragEvent) => {
    dragEvent.preventDefault();
    if (!elBody.classList.contains(dragClass)) {
      elBody.classList.add(dragClass);
    }
  });
  elBody.addEventListener("dragleave", () => {
    elBody.classList.remove(dragClass);
  });
  elBody.addEventListener("drop", (dropEvent) => {
    dropEvent.preventDefault();
    elBody.classList.remove(dragClass);
    [...dropEvent.dataTransfer.items].forEach((item, i) => {
      if (item.kind === "file") {
        const file = item.getAsFile();
        fReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file, 'utf-8');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Alternative to dataview

```js
const processFile = (arrayBuffer) => {
  let offset = 0;
  const outputArr = [];

  const firstInteger = new Int32Array(arrayBuffer.slice(offset, offset + 4))[0];
  console.log("First integer:", firstInteger);
  offset += 4;

  const int8View = new Int8Array(arrayBuffer);

  for (; offset < int8View.length; offset++) {
    const char = int8View[offset];
    if (char >= 32 && char <= 126) {
      outputArr.push(String.fromCharCode(char));
    } else if (char === 10) {
      outputArr.push("\n");
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = outputArr
    .join("")
    .replace(/%(\w+)/g, "<h2>$1</h2>");
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.drag-over {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

pre {
  margin-bottom: 120px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Drop a file here</h1>
<pre id="output"></pre>
<hr/>
<script>
  // file reader code - no modified except to add identifiers

  const fReader = new FileReader();
  fReader.onload = function(e) {
    const data = e.target.result;
    processFile(data);
  };
  const dragClass = "drag-over"
  elBody = document.querySelector("h1");
  elBody.addEventListener("dragover", (dragEvent) => {
    dragEvent.preventDefault();
    if (!elBody.classList.contains(dragClass)) {
      elBody.classList.add(dragClass);
    }
  });
  elBody.addEventListener("dragleave", () => {
    elBody.classList.remove(dragClass);
  });
  elBody.addEventListener("drop", (dropEvent) => {
    dropEvent.preventDefault();
    elBody.classList.remove(dragClass);
    [...dropEvent.dataTransfer.items].forEach((item, i) => {
      if (item.kind === "file") {
        const file = item.getAsFile();
        fReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file, 'utf-8');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: wow that works quite well, thanks you! I will have to play around with this to see how the other pieces of data are split up in this file

Comment: I was not so impressed with the second file (Spanish) it seems it might be RTF?

Comment: Yeah you can look in that repo for [my non-binary parsing solution which is quite ugly](https://github.com/FiniteLooper/SongShowPlus-parser/blob/main/src/text-cleaner.ts). Not RTF data. Many other file format choose XML, which I much prefer to work with over this!

Comment: I had two versions. I posted the second one too in case you prefer that

Comment: They both seem to do the same thing. Is there any functional difference between the two?

Comment: Not that I know of for such small files, but since I had both, I might as well post them

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks again! I just finished re-writing my library using this as a starter. You can check it out here if you're curious, and see the large comment that describes the file format to break down the meaning of certain bytes that describe either the length or type of content that comes next: https://github.com/FiniteLooper/SongShowPlus-parser

Comment: @ChrisBarr Nice project. Well structured and with tests. Chapeau 